# windows 7 IIS working locally but not externally

Tags: iis, windows-7, web, external, port80

I have IIS installed with asp.net 4.0. I've managed to get my site showing on a static ip address and port forwarding is set up on my router but for some reason the site is still only showing locally and not on only external networks. Is there any obvious causes for this. I'm pretty new to IIS and have looked for hours so far to try and find out why I can access my site externally.

Currently the page just times out on external networks.

Any help would be great, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked out it was because I was pointing from my domain to the local IP and not Public IP, worked fine once I changed this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an issue with your network configuration rather than an IIS issue.

Here's a few things to try:

- Can you access the website from another machine on the same network?
- Is port 80 open on your router?
- Verify that your ISP is not blocking inbound requests on port 80